# How would i edit this vertical navigation menu - MAGENTO

Tags: magento, navigation

Ok. all i am trying todo now is add an image to the top of the navigation bar.

I photoshopped a picture of what i have now and what i am trying to achieve.

here is [my site](http://www.theshirt.org)

and here is a link to the [naviation module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes.html) in magento

Thanks guys you are always helpful here!

[image: What i have now]

[image: here is what i want]

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Is there a difference between those two pictures? What is the status at the moment, and what do you want?

Comment: For reference, it is bad form to delete a question and resubmit the same question with minor edits. You are allowed to edit your own question for a reason, please use that. In reference to this question, you should provide code samples as well as the steps you have attempted to perform the task you are asking.

Comment: hi, I will use edit function from now on. The difference between the two pictures is the "products" jpeg above the category bar. I have not submitted any code as i am new to web design and i dont know what code samples would be needed for this. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this question a bit specific, because it's related to specific plugin. 
I suggest you to  use template path hints to find out what file you have to edit. You could enable template path hints for specific store view in System/Configuration/Developer/Debug/Template Path Hints. This option will appear only when you enable specific store view in Current Configuration Scope on the top of left column. It will display hints around blocks on frontend.
You might also find useful official magento design guide: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/

Comment: Hi, i believe i have now found the template, layout and CSS files for this plugin. As a noobie what next steps do you recommend i take? i can post the files here if need be

Comment: What is your goal, just add an image? Find the place where it should be in phtml and insert image there.